# effective memory bandwidth from strided memory access

Tags: cuda, gpu, stride, memory-bandwidth

Suppose I have a kernel which performs strided memory access as follows:

```
__global__ void strideExample (float *outputData, float *inputData, int stride=2) 
{
        int index = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x) * stride;
        outputData[index] = inputData[index]; 
}
```

I understand that accesses with a stride size of 2 will result in a 50% load/store efficiency, since half of the elements involved in the transaction are not used (becoming wasted bandwidth). How do we proceed to calculate the load/store efficiency for larger stride sizes? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general:

```
load efficiency = requested loads / effective loads
```

Where `requested loads` is the number of bytes that the software *requested to read* and `effective loads` is the number of bytes that the hardware actually *had to read*. Same formula applies for stores.

Perfectly coalesced accesses have an efficiency of 1.

Your code requests exactly `(blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x) * sizeof(float)` bytes. Assuming `outputData` is correctly aligned (as are pointers returned by `cudaMalloc`), the hardware will have to read `(blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x) * sizeof(float) * stride` bytes, rounded up to the transaction size (128 bytes for SM/L1, 32 bytes for L1/L2).

Assuming your block size is large enough, the rounding to the transaction size becomes negligible and you can simplify the equation to just `1 / stride`, which gives in this case a load efficiency of approx ~16.7%.

Comment: Ok thanks! Let's say we have a stride size of 6 in the above question, how do we compute the load efficiency?

Comment: Is it the same for CUDA Compute Cabability 1.1 and 1.2?